# Multi-threaded insertion of elements into list infinite loop

Tags: c, multithreading

I am new to c programming and to multi-threading, and I am trying to write a program that will create multiple threads, and have each thread insert an element into a sorted doubly linked list with a dummy node. The purpose of my project was actually to synchronize insertion, deletion, lookup functions of the linked list but because of this bug, I cant even get to a point to have the race conditions. Here is my code.

```
//---------------------In a header file------------------


struct SortedListNode
{
    struct SortedListElement *prev;
    struct SortedListElement *next;
    const char *key;
};

typedef struct SortedListNode SortedList_t;
typedef struct SortedListNode SortedListElement_t;


void SortedList_insert(SortedList_t *list, SortedListElement_t *element)
{
    if (list->next == NULL && list->prev == NULL)
    {
        list->next = element;
        list->prev = element;
        element->next = list;
        element->prev = list;
        return;
    }

    int flag = 0;
    SortedListElement_t *currElement = list;
    while (flag == 0)
    {
        if (currElement->key == NULL)
        {
            currElement = currElement->next;
        }
        else if (strcmp(element->key,currElement->key) <=0)
        {
            element->prev = currElement->prev;
            element->next = currElement;
            currElement->prev->next = element;
            currElement->prev = element;
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if (currElement->next->key == NULL)
        {
            currElement->next = element;
            list->prev = element;
            element->next = list;
            element->prev = currElement;
            flag = 1;



        }
        else
        {
            currElement = currElement->next;
        }
    }
    return;
}

//-----------------------------In the source file----------------------

struct arg_struct {
  SortedList_t *list;
  SortedListElement_t ** element_array;
};

int num_iterations=10;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{


  int num_threads = 2;


  pthread_t threads[num_threads];

  struct arg_struct args;
  args.list = (SortedList_t *)malloc(sizeof(SortedList_t));
  args.list->next = NULL;
  args.list->prev = NULL;
  args.list->key = NULL;

  SortedListElement_t *element_array[(num_threads * num_iterations)];

  char * tempKey[(num_threads * num_iterations)];

  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i < (num_threads * num_iterations); i++)
  {
    element_array[i] = (SortedList_t *)malloc(sizeof(SortedList_t));
    element_array[i]->next = NULL;
    element_array[i]->prev = NULL;
    tempKey[i] = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    random_key_generator(tempKey[i],3);
    element_array[i]->key = tempKey[i];
  }

  args.element_array = element_array;


    for(int i=0;i <num_threads;i++)
    {

      pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,&aux_operations, (void *) &args);
    }

      for(int i=0;i <num_threads;i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);


  return 0;
}

void random_key_generator(char *dest,size_t length)
{
  char charset[] = "0123456789"
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  while (length-- > 0) {
    size_t index = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX * (sizeof charset - 1);
    *dest++ = charset[index];
  }
  *dest = '\0';
}

void *aux_operations(void *arguments)
{

  struct arg_struct *args = arguments;
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<num_iterations;i++)
    SortedList_insert(args->list,args->element_array[i]);
}
```

The program works correctly when using only 1 thread, but gets stuck in infinite loop inside SortedList_insert function when using more than 1 thread. I am not sure if my implementation of SortedList_insert is causing the bug or the way I handle the threads.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you doing any locking of the list or of elements.

A multi-threaded program (process) has multiple theads that execute in "parallel", meaning the scheduler of the OS allocates each thread a timeslice and pre-empts it when the the slice is over and gives another process (thread) a time-slice.

This means that while an insertion is under way, the thread performing the insertion may be pre-empted. The insertion is incomplete. If another thread now operates on the list, it may find it in disorder. Undefined behavior will now occur.

So you must lock the list or element being processed. I am not a thread guru so cannot give you the names of the functions to call to lock the list (something like semaphores will do the job).

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this but I tried locking the whole function with mutex, and the same bug still occurs. So I am not sure if the bug is caused by a race condition.